# TestStack White: Cannot find MenuItem object within a ContextMenu using AutomationID

Tags: wpf, popup, contextmenu, ui-automation, white-framework

I am using TestStack White for UI automation of a Windows WPF chat application. I can get the **Add** button searching by AutomationID which pops a ContextMenu with two MenuItems to select to add contact or to create a group.

When I try to get the **Create group** MenuItem using its automationID, it throws an exception:

> TestStack.White.AutomationException: Failed to get AutomationId = mitem_createGroup

These are the methods I've tried to get the MenuItem but failed:

```
mainWindow.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("mitem_createGroup")).Click();

mainWindow.MenuBar.MenuItemBy(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("mitem_createGroup")).Click();

mainWindow.Get<MenuBar>(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("ContextMenu"));

var createGrpBtn = mainWindow.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("Create group"));

mainWindow.PopupMenu("Create group");
```

I am out of ideas and need help figuring this out.

---

**Edit:**
Here is the XAML for the contextmenu and menuitems. **The ContextMenu is actually that of an ImageButton**

```
<ContextMenu StaysOpen="False" FontSize="14" Style="{DynamicResource ContextMenuStyle}">
    <MenuItem Height="32" Header="{lex:Loc STRING_MAIN_WINDOW_ADD_CONTACT}" Name="mitem_addContact" Click="mitem_addContact_Click">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="{svg:SvgImage /ChatApp;component/Images/add_contact.svg}"  />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Height="32" Header="{lex:Loc STRING_MAIN_WINDOW_CREATE_GROUP}" Name="mitem_createGroup" Click="mitem_createGroup_Click">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="{svg:SvgImage /ChatApp;component/Images/add_group.svg}" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: can you post your xaml?

Comment: @FrancescoB. I've added the xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this post on SO: [Find option to right click c# White/TestStack UI Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713272/find-option-to-right-click-c-sharp-white-teststack-ui-automation)

You cannot get ContextMenu simply by using `Window.Get<T>` and I was in the right direction when I tried to get the ContextMenu popup, but i was doing it wrong. (See in question the last method i tried).

The SO link helped me get the solution:

```
PopUpMenu popup = mainWindow.Popup;
Menu createGroup_item = popup.ItemBy(
    SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("mitem_createGroup")
);
createGroup_item.Click();
```

Comment: @FrancescoB.Still got a few hours left before I can mark it as the correct answer